# Callout view works segue when click outside the accessory button in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, dictionary

there's a problem when doing the calloutView in annotationView.

I create a button in callout view

`rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)`

It is doing fine when callout shows, but there's other ViewController I needs to segue to, and I define the AccessoryView in mapView method.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if (control as? UIButton)?.buttonType == .DetailDisclosure {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Show Photo", sender: view) 
    }
}
```

Thing is that I click outside of the button within callout, it still works the segue, and I don't want that happens when I don't click the specific part of detailDisclosure Button.

How do I fix that?

Thanks very much for helping.

Comment: I'v tried changing the frame of the button, nothing's different.